# URL schema for launching Notes app in iOS

Tags: ios

Is there a URL schema for launching the built in Notes app in iOS 6? I have seen significantly more work than what is provided here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html

Specifically, the entire settings app seems to have URL schemas for each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sad fact is that if Apple does not publish a means to do it, any hack will surely break in the future. It use to be possible with a hack to open Settings, but then one day it stopped working.

The best thing to do is enter a bug report at bug reporter.apple.com and request this feature - that said apple won't do it unless they get lots of such requests.